# POST file as binary body using CloseableHttpClient Java

Tags: java, file-upload, upload, httpclient, postfile

I post a file using form-data but file is uploading corrupted. I need to post it as binary. How can I do it in Java using HttpClient?

"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set it like below:

```
post.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
```